# How do you fetch a Record Type ID in a Lightning Web Component using the DeveloperName?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm using `getObjectInfo` from `lightning/uiObjectInfoApi` to get record types for my object but I notice the `recordTypeInfos` response **does not include the DeveloperName for the Record Type**. This seems to be a glaring oversight in the design as the record type names can be changed at any time, potentially breaking a component. Is there another method to fetch a record type by DeveloperName within a Lightning Web Component or would I need to implement this in Apex?

Example code below:

```js
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import CASE_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Case';

export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: CASE_OBJECT })
    objectInfo({error, data}) {
        if(data) {
            const recordTypes = data.recordTypeInfos;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(recordTypes));
        }
    }

}
```

This will log an object like this:

```js
salesforce-id: {
    available: true,
    defaultRecordTypeMapping: false,
    master: false,
    name: "Record Type Name",
    recordTypeId: "salesforce-id"
}
```

There isn't a `DeveloperName` that I can match the ID on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, since (as of this post and API version 50.0) the [UI API does not expose RecordTypeInfo DeveloperNames](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_responses_record_type_info.htm) and instead the following properties:

| Property Name | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| available | Boolean | Indicates whether this record type is available to the context user when creating a record. |
| defaultRecordTypeMapping | Boolean | Indicates whether this record type mapping is the default for the associated object. |
| master | Boolean | Indicates whether this record type is the master record type. The master record type is the default record type that’s used when a record has no custom record type associated with it. |
| name | String | The record type's label name. |
| recordTypeId | String | The ID of the record type. |

The best solution I've come up with is to create a utility class and method to return a `Map<String, Id>` to grab a Record Type ID when you know the `DeveloperName` (which is the case with most of my components).

```java
public static Map<String, Id> getDeveloperNameToIdMap(String sObjectName) {
    List<Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rtis = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObjectName).getDescribe().RecordTypeInfos;
    Schema.RecordTypeInfo defaultRecordTypeInfo;

    Map<String, Id> recordTypeMap = new Map<String, Id>();
    for(Schema.RecordTypeInfo rti : rtis) {
        recordTypeMap.put(rti.getDeveloperName(), rti.getRecordTypeId());
    }

    return recordTypeMap;
}
```

The method can be adjusted as needed to filter out active record types and whether or not the running user has access to the record type.